# Predictive Analysis using Java

Tags: r, weka, mahout, rjava, jri

I am working on a Spring based Web application which performs Predictive Analysis based on the user historical data and come up with offers to users. I need to implement a Predictive Analysis or any regression kind of functionality which gives a confidence score/prediction to present those offers. I am a Java developer and looked at Weka, Mahout to get the desired result. But both the tools dont provide good documentation and it is highly difficult to proceed with them. I need a suggestion regarding Java based analytics API to process my data using regression or Neural Networks or Decision Trees and provides a confidence score depicting customers probablity on buying the product in future.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise you to keep trying with Weka. It's a great tool, not only for implementation but also to get an idea of which algorithms will work for you, what your data looks like, etc.
The book is worth the price, but if you're not willing to buy it, [this wiki page](http://weka.wikispaces.com/How+do+I+use+WEKA%27s+classes+in+my+own+code?) might be a good starting point.

It might be best to start with testing, not programming - I believe the quote goes "60% of the difficulty of machine learning is understanding the dataset". Play around with the Weka GUI, find out what works best for you and your data, and do try some of the meta-classifiers (boosting, bagging, stacking); they often give great results (at the cost of processing time).

Comment: Thanks EagleV_Attnam, One more concern for me is I heard that Weka is not preferable for huge data sets. My application may have few million items in a data set. Did you know how much impact it would have on performance.

Comment: I don't know about that, sorry. I only ever used it for smaller sets.

Comment: When you say "huge data sets" , what exactly size?

Answer (score 3):

I've just finished working on a long project that involves building a GUI with JavaFx and R using the JRI package, it uses forecasting from the `forecast` package in R.

if you'll choose this solution (JavaFX + R) , all the statistical packaging of R will be at use, R has great documentation for this, but the interface `jri` is a challenge.
The program i built is in a stand alone mode, not a web start.

Most of the fuss regards setting up all environment variables, and passing parameters to the JVM, the big problem is for deployment, you need to make sure your clients have R, and to setup all the links between R and Java in their PC.

If you're interested in any prediction analysis (trees, regressions..) in R using Java /JRI, let me know and ill post it.

Comment: Thank you so much Yehoshaphat. Yes I am very much in Predictive Analysis using R. Infact R was my initial choice when I start the project, but I could not find any reliable information about the performance overhead involved in call R from Java and hence looking for an Java based API. If you provide me information regarding Predictive Analysis, that could be really helpful to me.

Comment: I'm A bit confused, before you start learning JRI, are you familiar with the R syntax?

Comment: I am not familiar with R Syntax but as I have not found any other alternatives, I think I should have to go with R

Comment: Good choice, then in that case, before you start JRI, its important you know how to use R, the problem with R is that its a bit hard to know were to start, look at this for further advice:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4556524/whats-the-way-to-learn-r

Comment: I hope this was the answer you looked for